Getting Promise(<Pending>) when I try to send out contents with JSON file
I'm trying to convert a small (single page) PHP app to Javascript but having trouble accessing the contents of the JSON file.
I think it's down to how I've written the JS, but as an example:
async function fetchLocalFile(filePath) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(filePath);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        const fileContents = await response.text();
        return fileContents;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching the file:', error);
    }
}

// Usage example
const filePath = 'example.json';
fetchLocalFile(filePath).then(contents => {
    console.log(contents); // this works, I get the whole json file to console
});

console.log(contents["name"][0]); // Error: contents not defined.

So my questions:

How do I get contents to exist outside the fetchLocalFile request?
I'd like to use this on other, similar pages. How would I move the function to another JS file (I'd like to make it as a shareable 'utility' function set, separate to whatever JS code I'm writing per app to save me re-writing the function).


Even if you make contents a global variable, the last console.log() call runs before the async operation has completed. You will have to delay that call until after fetchLocalFile() completes; for instance, you can put it in a click event listener.

Ugh, I've been trying to debug this for so long I'd forgotten that I wasn't calling it anymore! Thanks for that. Would an 'onload' in the body do the trick?
That leads me to my second question, I have a series of these apps that I want to make/convert from php, I had a set up in the earlier version where I'd have one file supplying code common to all the apps (like showing diagnostics,  load 'x' JSON file, etc.) and a second that did the job relevant to this page.

No, it won't. You should just put everything that needs the value immediately in the .then() function. If you need it available later, assign to a global variable.

global variable. OK will try that, thanks again!
